# RBS won't work with default "0x" SID credentials

Tags: 2010, sql-server, remote-blob-storage, rbs

I'm trying to get RBS to work without having to specify credentials for each user (SID) in the RBS tables. [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg316770%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) notes that default credentials starting with 0x can be used:

> Each credential entry must be associated with a database user and a
>   BLOB store. **A special value of 0x can be specified for the database
>   user, meaning that the credential will be used for every user that
>   doesn't have a unique credential defined for them.** Other user
>   identifiers must correspond to SQL Server user ID values obtained by
>   calling suser_sid().

So I use stored procedure `EXEC [mssqlrbs].[rbs_sp_set_blob_store_credential] 0x, @rbsId, @username, @pwd` to set the default credentials as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrbs/archive/2010/08/05/rbs-security-model.aspx). However, this fails when trying to store files in RBS as no credentials get passed to the RBS provider, i.e. default credentials are ignored. As expected, everything works correctly if instead 0x I specify the proper user SID from `sys.database_principals`. The only scenario that doesn't work is when only SID="0x" credentials exist in the database.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? Is this a bug?